# Concurrent TCP Server in Tcl

Tags: tcp, tcl

I have to write a TCP Server for my legacy application (standalone) to create a client - server interface for it.

I am planning to write pre-forked (can't user threads because of thread safety issues) concurrent server. I need following two things.

Q. A simple example program (may be an echo-server) explaining concerns and ingredients of a pre-forked concurrent server.

Q. Server will exchange data in JSON format. How to configure client socket, so that server know properly whether the client has completely written the json on channel or it is still in the process of writing.

Comment: Can't _what_ user threads? You accidentally the verb.

Answer (score 3):

Why use threads or forks? Just use Tcl's event-driven model.

```
proc accept {sock host port} {
    fconfigure $sock -blocking 0 -buffering line
    fileevent $sock readable [list readsock $sock]
}

proc readsock {sock} {
    global sockbuf
    if {[read $sock data] < 0} {
       if {[eof $sock]} {
           # Socket was closed by remote
           unset sockbuf($sock)
           close $sock
           return
       }
    }
    append sockbuf($sock) $data\n
    # Check if you got all the necessary data. For Tcl lists, use [info complete]
    if {[info complete $sockbuf($sock)]} {
        set data $sockbuf($sock)
        unset sockbuf($sock)
        # process data
        puts $sock $data
    }
}

socket -server accept 12345
vwait forever; # This will enter the event loop.
```

If you really need (or want) to use Threads, thread safety is also not a problem in Tcl.
But using forks usually end up in reimplementing more or less the [thread](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/thread.htm) API.

If you really want to fork, then here are some of the problems that you will encounter:

1. You have to communicate with the children. I suggest using pipes.
2. You have to pass the socket from the master to the other children. While this might be possible with unix domain sockets at C level, but I don't know about any Tcl extension that can do that.
3. You have to write the pool stuff yourself (or use a C library for that).

IMHO it is not worth all the needed effort for forks.

Comment: For the `is this complete json data` I suggest try to parse it and catch any errors that might occur.

Comment: Tcl doesn't handle taking _server_ sockets as an external channel, but client sockets (including the sockets produced when a client connects to a server) work fine as things passed as stdin/stdout to a subprocess.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: This is a fabulous example of a concurrent server without thread or fork. But I think using this, I cannot give users the feel of a "session". I need to spawn a Tcl interpreter for each new client and maintain it till the client is done. So all the variables and function created by the client in request 1 should last till request N. Can we do this without using thread or fork. In case I have to use fork, then is there any way in Tcl so that an event is generated whenever a child dies, some kind of polling each child and parent process only doing child management.

Comment: @VivekJha Take a look at the [interp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/interp.htm) command (I don't know any other language that actually export this to the language level itself). If you do the fork, then you have to use [fileevent](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/fileevent.htm)s (like in my code) on the child.